# How to use spread function and left join data frames (DF1, DF2, DF3, upto DF 621) in a forloop?

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop, iteration

I have data frames (DF1, DF2, DF3, DF4 upto DF621)
I want to use spread function on them before left joining (by column GEOID) them inside a for-loop.

I should finally have one data frame containing all my data frames (DF1 to DF621).

Every `DF[i]` Data Frame contains 4 columns: `normalized, GEOID, Name, variable`.

for e.g.

```
DF21spread <- spread(DF21, variable, normalized)

test <- spread(DF20, variable, normalized) %>%

  left_join(DF21spread, by ='GEOID')
```

Answer (score 1):

A solution is to first `rbind` the data.frames together and then spread.

```
library(dplyr)

DF1 <- iris[1:50, ]
DF2 <- iris[51:100, ]
DF3 <- iris[101:150, ]

dfs <- mget(ls(patter = "DF"))

bind_rows(dfs, .id = 'id')
```